# Common onClickListener in activity doesn't work for all fragments which are in turn created from same layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have implemented a `viewPager` using a single activity and two fragments. Both the fragments are created using a single layout. In that common layout i have two `EditText` and one button. I have implemented the `onClickListener` inside the activity for both the fragments.
When I am clicking on button from the first fragment everything is working fine but when I am clicking from the second fragment the values entered in `EditText` is coming as empty.
My Activity Class :

```
public class AddNewExpenseActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager_fragment);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // When the tab is selected, switch to the
                // corresponding page in the ViewPager.
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

     // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
     actionBar.addTab( actionBar.newTab().setText("Fixed Expense").setTabListener(tabListener));
     actionBar.addTab( actionBar.newTab().setText("Variable Expense").setTabListener(tabListener));

     pager.setOnPageChangeListener(
             new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                     // When swiping between pages, select the
                     // corresponding tab.
                     getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                 }
             });




    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

            Fragment fm = null;
            switch(pos) {

            case 0: 
                fm = new AddFixedExpenseFragment();
                break;
            case 1: 
                fm = new AddVariableExpenseFragment();
                break;
            default: 
                fm = new AddFixedExpenseFragment();
                break;
            }
            return fm;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }       
    }
```

AddFixedExpenseFragment Fragment :

```
public class AddFixedExpenseFragment extends Fragment{

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
            // properly.
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_add_new_expense, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

}
```

AddVariableExpenseFragment Fragment :

```
public class AddVariableExpenseFragment extends Fragment{

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    private int year,month,day;
    private EditText dateValueView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_add_new_expense, container, false);

        TextView dateLabelView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dateLabel);
        dateValueView = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dateValue);
        ImageView datePickerView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

        dateLabelView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dateValueView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        datePickerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        datePickerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment df = new DatePickerDialogFragment();
                df.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            year=yr;
            month=monthOfYear;
            day=dayOfMonth;

            updateDate(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);

        }

        private void updateDate(int year, int i, int dayOfMonth) {

            dateValueView.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + i + "/" + year);
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Two days no answer!!